# Когда слово "отель" стало относиться к мужскому роду?

Tags: заимствования, род

"После обеда...виноват, после завтрака, мы вышли на улицу: наша отель стояла на углу, на перекрестке." Фрегат "Паллада". И.А. Гончаров. (Цитируемые строки относятся к 1853 г.)

Answer (score 3):

Интересная информация "нашлась" в [**Историческом словаре галлицизмов русского языка**](https://gallicismes.academic.ru/27526/%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C):
*Только **с 1866 г.** новое слово <отель> появляется в словарях.*

Именно в это время и выходит первое издание *Толкового словаря живого великорусского языка* *[**В. И. Даля**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enc2p/293942)* (1863-1866) [1863 (т. 1), 1865 (тт. 2, 3), 1866 (т. 4)], в котором видим:
**отель**
*муж., франц.* частный дворец; /обширная гостиница

Вполне естественно, что одномоментно мужской род за иноземным словом "закрепиться" не мог:

*Она повела свое дело так хорошо, что два, три года отделение ее прозвано было, хотя и неофициально, польскою отелью...*
[**И. Лажечников. Внучка панцирного боярина. 1868**](https://books.google.ee/books?id=y4f4CAAAQBAJ&pg=PT30&lpg=PT30&dq=%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%8E&source=bl&ots=7KsgyziBkI&sig=soIEzLE1Fex2894q2zAMxjcjw9g&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj7zL_bouTXAhXHVRoKHct7C_44PBDoAQg4MAI#v=onepage&q=%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%8E&f=false)

Answer (score 1):

Более позднее упоминание слова "отель" в женском роде удалось найти в ["Современной идиллии"](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=NEw8AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA128&dq=%22%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%22&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwit08zfl-TXAhXB1RQKHYcyCHoQ6AEIPzAF#v=onepage&q=%22%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%22%20-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%20-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D1%8B&f=false) В.П. Авенариуса, 1874 г. издания. Очевидно, что конкретной даты перехода на мужской род здесь быть не может. Даже сейчас любители определённого, кхм, стиля языка нередко используют женский род.

Для интересующихся вопросом вариативности родовой принадлежности существительных может быть интересна [вот эта статья](http://rusgram.ru/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%B4) (там в примерах есть слово "отель", в частности) и, особенно, [работа Савчука](http://www.dialog-21.ru/digests/dialog2011/materials/en/pdf/56.pdf), на которую она ссылается.